# Read list of names from CSV into R

Tags: r

I have a text file of names, separated by commas, and I want to read this into whatever in R (data frame or vector are fine).  I try read.csv and it just reads them all in as headers for separate columns, but 0 rows of data.  I try header=FALSE and it reads them in as separate columns.  I could work with this, but what I really want is one column that just has a bunch of rows, one for each name.  For example, when I try to print this data frame, it prints all the column headers, which are useless, and then doesn't print the values.  It seems like it should be easily usable, but it appears to me one column of names would be easier to work with.

Comment: Without seeing the file it's difficult to tell. Maybe that data is not in tabular form but is a long sequence of strings separated by commas. If this is the case try `scan(what = 'character', etc)`. (Check out the file first with a text editor.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes, that's what it is.  It's a long sequence of strings separated by commas.  I'm trying to read it in as one column, even though that does not appear to be the default behavior with R.

Comment: If that's the case I would try `dat <- scan(file = your_filename, what = 'character', sep = ',')`.

Comment: Note that scan accepts a "sep" argument, so maybe `dat <- scan(what = 'character', file = your_file, sep=",")` to separate each set of characters between commas.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Can you make this an answer?  This seems to be like exactly what I was looking for.  I appreciate the other answers as well, as it helps me learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the OP asked me to, I'll post the comment above as an answer.
It's very simple, and it comes from some practice in reading in sequences of data, numeric or character, using `scan`.

```
dat <- scan(file = your_filename, what = 'character', sep = ',')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read.csv` are read string as header, but then just extract names (using `names`) and put this into a `data.frame`:

```
data.frame(x = names(read.csv("FILE")))
```

For example:

```
write.table("qwerty,asdfg,zxcvb,poiuy,lkjhg,mnbvc",
            "FILE", col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
data.frame(x = names(read.csv("FILE")))

      x
1 qwerty
2  asdfg
3  zxcvb
4  poiuy
5  lkjhg
6  mnbvc
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

Make some test data:

```
# test data
list_of_names <- c("qwerty","asdfg","zxcvb","poiuy","lkjhg","mnbvc" )
list_of_names <- paste(list_of_names, collapse = ",")

list_of_names

# write to temp file
tf <- tempfile()
writeLines(list_of_names, tf)
```

You need this part:

```
# read from file
line_read <- readLines(tf)
line_read

list_of_names_new <- unlist(strsplit(line_read, ","))
```